# Execute a function after Activity or Fragment closed

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

My MainActivity Contains a Navigation Drawer.
In this drawer there is an item called "sign in".
In addition, I created a static variable:

```js
public static boolean SIGNED = false;
```

The purpose is that after user clicked on "Sign in", he will get an activity (or fragment) that he will insert his credentials into it. Then, if the credentials are correct - the navigation drawer will contain "Sign out" item instead, and will open some other activity/fragment (for singed in users only. Let's say "HomeFragment").

My login activity contains:

```js
           case R.id.bSign_in:
                signIn();
                finish();
                break;
```

But of course I cannot solve the problem with this code (in the MainActivity):

```js
            case R.id.nav_sign_in:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
                if (SIGNED)
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                return true;
```

What can I do to solve it?
If the solutions are different between activity and fragment - I'm interested in both.

Comment: Is your question how to change activities and immediately open a new fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard way to execute some logic after Activity returns is to use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html), after activity returns - onActivityResult is executed where you can execute your code.

In case of fragment, you can directly call your Activity (activity that owns this fragment) function when it gets closed (ie. user pressed login button).